# Squaring both sides of an inequality

Tags: inequality

I found that I can square both sides of an inequality as long as both sides are non-negative. But if we do, for example, this inequality:

```
FourthRoot(x^2-9) < sqrt(2-x)  //^2
sqrt(x^2-9) < 2-x
```

Why can't I still raise to the second power? I know that *2-x* must be positive as *sqrt(2-x)* is positive.

Comment: You can square both sides if x > 2

Comment: Please, could you give me an explanation?

Comment: Square both sides, solve the resulting quadratic inequality and then impose x > 2 on your solutions. I'd type more, but I'm not on my computer right now.

Comment: I would impose $x^2\ge 9$ and $x\le 2$ as constraints on the domain for the original inequality to be defined, ie $x\le -3$.